# Facebook ProfilePictureView adding padding to top and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently trying to make a gridView of facebook profile pictures. Now it's all setup and working nicely except for one problem. It seems that whenever the profile picture is set above a certain size it starts to add padding to the top and bottom of the image.

I'm trying to get a 2 column grid of profile picture, here are the results.

Using `fill_parent`

[image]

Using `wrap_content`. No extra padding top or bottom but doesn't fill the necessary space

[image]

Using 3 columns and `fill_parent` (This is how I want it to look but with 2 columns instead)

[image]

I've tried setting the the cell height, changing the facebook `ProfilePictureView` size, and other fixes but it seems that the padding is caused by the `ProfilePictureView` itself. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

I can add any additional code if needed.

Comment: How are you using the ProfilePictureView? Can you post code or the xml where you're including it?

Comment: What is the aspect ratio of the profile pictures? I can see that the width you want is screenWidth/2, but what's the height? I have a solution for taking up the whole width / column count in a `GridView` or `GridLayoutManager`, but that's for square grid items. Please post your GridView xml and grid item xml.

Comment: Figured it out. By setting the width and height manually to exactly half the screen width in `dp` programmatically I was able to solve the padding issue. I only really got away with this because the profile pictures are all exactly square.